# Unable to connect to kafka MSK using segmentio/kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am trying to create a function that checks if a topic exists in my AWS MSK

```
func KafkaTopicExist(kafkabroker string, topic string) bool {
conn, err := kafka.Dial("tcp", kafkabroker)
if err != nil {
    log.WithError(err).Warn("Kafka broker connection error")
}
defer conn.Close()

partitions, err := conn.ReadPartitions()
if err != nil {
    log.WithError(err).Warn("Can not get all partitions to obtain ")
}

m := map[string]struct{}{}

for _, p := range partitions {
    m[p.Topic] = struct{}{}
}
_, exists := m[topic]
return exists
```

}
kafkabroker is a string that takes MSK TLS private endpoint. I get a connection error.
while using PLAINTEXT endpoint works.
am I missing something is the config?

Comment: Where exactly do you provide TLS certs for the connection?

Comment: Actually I dont need to authenticate to the cluster! I just need to communicate and exchange data using TLS, without auth

Comment: In Java, for example, JKS files are used for TLS authentication. Certainly, Go needs something similar for providing a public key for data encryption to Kafka

Comment: Still did not figure out a way to do it with go